# How to filter in the frequency domain

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a signal and I have a filter.

I want to convert the signal into frequency domain and then filter it with my filter.

Converting the signal into frequency domain is easy, but how do I filter the signal now?

This is my filter:

```
filter_2 = firceqrip(2,0.6,[0.05 0.03]);
```

This is my signal:

```
freqs = [0.08, 0.2, 0.32, 0.4];
periods = 1./ freqs;
t_max = 4 * periods(1);
t = linspace(0, t_max, 50);

signal = sin(2*pi*0.08*t) + sin(2*pi*0.2*t) + sin(2*pi*0.32*t) + sin(2*pi*0.4*t);

% to find the fft of the signal
N = 64;
signal_spect = abs (fft(signal,N));
signal_spect = fftshift(signal_spect);
F = [-N/2:N/2-1]/N;
```

now how do I filter the previous signal with my filter?
I tried doing this fft(filter_2) but it didn't work out, it's probably a wrong approach, but I do not know what else to do

any help is appreicated

Comment: Are you allowed to change the "2" in the `firceqrip()` function  to another value?

Comment: @mehmet will it make a difference??
i should use a filter of order 2, that's why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering in frequency domain is simply multiplication element by element. Therefore, signal and filter in the frequency domain must be same length. Here in your code, the argument in the `firceqrip()` is "2" but I think it should be 63. Or, you should take N element fft of your order of 2 filter. I don' t know if you can change these. If you did that, your code would work. But again, I don' t know if the result is reasonable:

```
filter_2 = firceqrip(2,0.6,[0.05 0.03]); 

freqs = [0.08, 0.2, 0.32, 0.4];
periods = 1./ freqs;
t_max = 4 * periods(1);
t = linspace(0, t_max, 50);

signal = sin(2*pi*0.08*t) + sin(2*pi*0.2*t) + sin(2*pi*0.32*t) + sin(2*pi*0.4*t);

% // to find the fft of the signal
N = 64;
signal_spect = fft(signal, N);
F = [-N/2:N/2-1]/N;

output = abs( fftshift( ( fft(filter_2, N) .* signal_spect) ) );
stem(F, output)
```

Comment: but i can't have a filter with the order 63, my filter is of order 2, I am really confused.

Comment: @sadbee I' ve edited my answer above. The result of filtering change a little. Check this out, maybe it makes more sense..